# No ObservableObject of type found after logout

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I'm currently trying to create an app that fetches data from Firebase and i ran into some problems. I'm trying to make a profile card where some data attached to the user.uid would be shown, but once i logout and log back in i get an error saying:

```
Fatal error: No ObservableObject of type UserDataManager found. A View.environmentObject(_:) for UserDataManager may be missing as an ancestor of this view.
```

The App File:

```
import SwiftUI
import Firebase

@main
struct Darbo_ManijaApp: App {

@UIApplicationDelegateAdaptor(AppDelegate.self) var appDelegate

var body: some Scene {
    WindowGroup {
        let viewModel = AppViewModel()
        let userdataManager = UserDataManager()
        ContentView()
            .environmentObject(viewModel)
            .environmentObject(userdataManager)
    }
}
}

class AppDelegate: NSObject, UIApplicationDelegate {

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey : Any]? = nil) -> Bool {
    FirebaseApp.configure()
    return true
}

}
```

The UserDataManager file:

```
import Foundation
import Firebase

class UserDataManager: ObservableObject {

@Published var userFirstName: String = ""

init() {
    fetchUser()
}

func fetchUser() {
    let db = Firestore.firestore()
    let userID = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid ?? "Not Found"
    
    db.collection("users").document(userID)
        .addSnapshotListener { documentSnapshot, error in
            guard let document = documentSnapshot else {
                print("Error fetching document: \(error!)")
                return
            }
            
            guard let data = document.data() else {
                print("Document data was empty.")
                return
            }
            print("Fetched Data")
            self.userFirstName = data["firstname"] as? String ?? ""
        }
}
}
```

ContentView File:

```
struct ContentView: View {

@EnvironmentObject var userdataManager: UserDataManager
@EnvironmentObject var viewModel : AppViewModel
var body: some View {
    if viewModel.isSignedIn {
        
        UIKitTabView {
            JobListView().environmentObject(userdataManager).environmentObject(viewModel).tab(title: "Pradžia", image: "network")
            JobListView().tab(title: "Žinutės", image: "message")
            LoginView().tab(title: "Paskyra", image: "person")
            
        }
    } else {
        LoginView()
    }
}
}
```

And the JobsList view:

```
struct JobListView: View {

@EnvironmentObject var viewModel : AppViewModel
@EnvironmentObject var userdataManager: UserDataManager
let firebaseUserID = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid ?? "Not Found"

var body: some View {
    
    NavigationView{
        ScrollView{
            VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 0) {
                Text("Test")
                Text("User ID is: \(firebaseUserID)")
                
                Text("My Name is: \(userdataManager.userFirstName)")

                ForEach(jobData, id: \.id) { job in
                    JobCardView(job: job)
                }
            }
            .frame(minWidth: 0,
                   maxWidth: .infinity,
                   minHeight: 0,
                   maxHeight: .infinity)
            .padding()
        }
        .navigationBarItems(leading:
                                HStack{
            Image("TextDM")
                .resizable()
                .scaledToFit()
                .frame(height: 15)
        })
        .navigationBarItems(trailing:
                                HStack{
            
            Button(action: {
                viewModel.signOut()
            }) {
                Image(systemName: "person.crop.circle")
                    .accentColor(Color.primary)
                
            }
        })
        
        .navigationBarTitle("")
        .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
        .onAppear(){
            userdataManager.fetchUser()
        }
    }
    .environmentObject(userdataManager)
    .environmentObject(viewModel)
}
}
```

At first i thought it might be the problem, because in the content view when the tabbaritem is called the object is not set, but even though i did it, the problem remains. As i mentioned, i get the error on the JobListView File where i use **Text("My Name is: (userdataManager.userFirstName)")** The first time the app launches and if im logged in, there are no error and .onAppear with objects work, as well as the logout, but once i logout and log back in, i get the above mentioned error. Any suggestions or tips on how to fix this?
Thanks in advance!

EDIT: Solved the issue. The problem was, that i was using a different TabView, that needed to include the ObservableObjects in every tab link. Thanks For the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot replicate the issue with my current setup, but
there are a few things I would do differently in your code.

in "Darbo_ManijaApp" put these outside of the "body"

```
let viewModel = AppViewModel()
let userdataManager = UserDataManager()
```

Make sure that in "ContentView" the sequence of @EnvironmentObject is "AppViewModel" first and then "UserDataManager".

importantly, also pass

```
.environmentObject(userdataManager).environmentObject(viewModel)
```

to the other "JobListView()".
And again make sure the sequence @EnvironmentObject is correct.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I tried out what you suggested, but now i'm getting this error:
** "The default FirebaseApp instance must be configured before the default Authinstance can be initialized. One way to ensure this is to call `FirebaseApp.configure()` in the App Delegate's `application(_:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:)` (or the `@main` struct's initializer in SwiftUI)."**